# One node Apache NiFi cluster

Tags: apache-nifi

I am setting up a secure cluster with NiFi 1.7.1 using an external Zookeeper

While I do plan to have 3 nodes in the cluster, at the moment I am only going to start one node.
Is that a valid cluster from NiFi standpoint.

The reason for my question is I get this SSL Handshake error during startup and I want to rule out that having single not is not the cause of this problem,

Thanks

Vijay

Comment: Without seeing your SSL handshake error, please be aware that Apache NiFi 1.7.1 enforces RFC 6125 so certificates need a valid `SubjectAlternateName` entry in order for validation to occur. If you generated the certificate using the NiFi TLS Toolkit (v 1.7.1+) you should be ok, but a legacy certificate with only a DN entry will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a single node can be run as a cluster.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I will look for the error in the SSL Handshake part.